# InvalidAuthenticityToken for rails api only application for post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors

I am using api-only applicaiton and keep getting errors on post request. Post request is coming from a front end application and I am also testing sample data with postman.

Here is the error I get everytime when trying to submit a request

```
HTTP Origin header (http://localhost:3000) didn't match request.base_url (http://localhost:4000)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 238)
```

I have rack-cors gem set up and origin pointing to localhost:3000.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:3000'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      credentials: true,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

Comment: The test server runs on port 4000 to avoid conflicting with the development server. Either add entries for both ports or use a conditional based on `Rails.env`.

Comment: Change your `origins 'http://localhost:3000'` to origins `http://localhost:4000`

Comment: @MUHAMMADSOBAN great now he broke the dev server instead...

Comment: Of course, I said about the local environment, and for dev would have to use different origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple allowed origins:

```
origins 'localhost:3000', 'localhost:4000'
```

You can also use a regular expression:

```
origins /\Ahttps?:\/\/localhost:\d{1,}$/
```

A possible better solution altogether is to avoid hardcoding the domain and use ENV vars.

However `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` is actually raised by the Rails CSRF protection which has nothing to do with CORS. Its a session based CSRF protection scheme for "classic apps" that you can remove in API's either by removing the middleware (preferable) or `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`.

Comment: Perfect, now skip_before_action is considered dangerous ? considering that rails is not checking for the authenticity_token during POST,PUT,PATCH request the serve?  Anything I should be careful about?

Comment: Is it more dangerous than any of the many other frameworks that don't have built in anti-csrf? Nope.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your base controller
like:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
```

to

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
```